# Regression vs. XGBoost vs deep learning for tabular data

Tags: regression, neural-networks, boosting

I am modelling a tabular dataset and getting better results with a DNN than XGB or linear regression models. The literature tells me this shouldn't be the case. Are there any specific instances when DNNs should outperform gradient boosted decision trees and/or regression methods? These data have a large number of highly interacting features. The model does not need to extrapolate outside the training data.

Comment: What literature tells you that one tool should always be superior to another one for all instances of a given problem class? Sounds like [a free lunch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_free_lunch_theorem) to me.

Comment: While it is theoretically possible for one class of models to be [stochastically dominated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_dominance) or [Pareto dominated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_efficiency) in some sense, I find that doesn't seem to be the case in practice. As Stephan alludes to via the notion of no free lunch theorems, there are provable results in which this cannot happen. But it is also a sort of folklore theorem that if something looks like a free lunch in ML, it isn't.

Comment: These are all universal approximators in various senses, so if you have a huge amount of data, the easy flexibility offered by deep learning might give you ad advantage when it comes to model fit.

Comment: @Dave Is linear regression "universal" in the sense that a function $f$ might be decomposed by

$$f = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} c_i \mathbb{I}_i$$

where $c \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{I}_i$ indicates some arbitrary event? I think that would be a large space of functions.

Comment: @Galen That only covers a countable number of input points. If the true function hits points on a continuum, then what happens for the uncountable many points not considered by your sum? // However, the Stone-Weierstrass theorem can be thought of as a kind of universal approximation theorem for linear (polynomial) regression, and it doesn’t rely on a countable output space. The output space could be $[a,b]\subset\mathbb R$. (Yes, Stone-Weierstrass puts restrictions on what functions can be approximated by polynomials. So does Cybenko.)

Comment: @Dave Ah yes, that works. I know these theorems. The SW theorem just didn't come to mind at that moment. So far I am unaware of any function approximation theorems that don't put *some* kind of restrictions on the class of functions being approximated. Often compactness and some kind of continuity (e.g. Lipschitz) is assumed, but I don't think these assumptions are problematic on many problems.